# Java generics in Kotlin: Use Java raw type as method parameter in Kotlin

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I'm looking at this class in Facebook sdk:

```
public final class ShareDialog extends 
                  FacebookDialogBase<ShareContent, Sharer.Result>
```

I want to have a method in Kotlin that accepts it's parent class, similar to the following:

```
fun shareToFacebook(shareDialog: FacebookDialogBase<ShareContent<*, *>, Sharer.Result>,
                    activity: Activity)
```

But when I try to call it form java:

```
tournamentPresenter.shareToFacebook(new ShareDialog(this), this);
```

I get compile time error:

`Error:(751, 45) error: incompatible types: ShareDialog cannot be converted to FacebookDialogBase<ShareContent<?,?>,Result>`

P.S. I know that it's better to not give share dialog to the presenter, I'm not going to do it, let's just use it as an example of the problem

Comment: What is your question? How to solve it? Or do you not understand the error?

Comment: Have you tried using `ShareContent<Any?, Any?>` or `ShareContent<Any, Any>` instead of `ShareContent<*, *>`?

Comment: @JornVernee I would like to know how to solve it, but more interested in knowing why, according to the docs https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html raw Java type should be representeer as Type<*> in Kotlin, but here it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the signature of the `ShareDialog` class, which uses a raw type.

```
public final class ShareDialog extends 
              FacebookDialogBase<ShareContent, Sharer.Result>
.................................^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And, even though the Kotlin doc says to use `*`, at a VM level that is equivalent to `?`, a wildcard. Since a `FacebookDialogBase<ShareContent, Sharer.Result>` is not assignable to a `FacebookDialogBase<ShareContent<?, ?>, Sharer.Result>` your call fails.

However, using a raw type *should* be semantically equivalent to using wildcards as type parameters. So you could do the generic equivalent of a reinterpret cast:

```
FacebookDialogBase<ShareContent<?, ?>, Sharer.Result> myVar = (FacebookDialogBase) new ShareDialog(this);
tournamentPresenter.shareToFacebook(myVar, this);
```

And things should still pretty much work the same.